# How to publish dynamic components in SDL Deployer file system maintaining the folder structure as in CME?

Tags: dynamic, components, tridion-2011

I have a scenario where my dynamic components available in CME should be published to the same folder path as in CME. Can I control the path where these dynamic components are published?

e.g) **CME Path** - C020 Global Content US English/Building Blocks/Dynamic Content/Article/Component1.xml
**Deployer File System Path** - D:\C020 Global Content US English/Building Blocks/Dynamic Content/Article/Component1.xml

**CME Path** - C050 Local Content Spanish/Building Blocks/Dynamic Content/Communication/Component2.xml
**Deployer File System Path** - D:\C050 Local Content Spanish\Building Blocks\Dynamic Content\Communication\Component2.xml

Comment: You should probably ask this question on the Tridion StackExchange site: http://tridion.stackexchange.com –

Answer (score 0):

You can define the path in the stroage config file on CDA Server in below tag.

```
 <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">

    <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Xml" cached="true" storageId="defaultDataFile" />
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".rel" cached="true" storageId="defaultDataFile" />
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".ascx" cached="true" storageId="defaultDataFile" />
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".html" cached="true" storageId="defaultDataFile" />
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".jpg" storageId="defaultFile" cached="true"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".gif" storageId="defaultFile" cached="true"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".pdf" storageId="defaultFile" cached="true"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".jpeg" storageId="defaultFile" cached="true"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".png" storageId="defaultFile" cached="true"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".ico" storageId="defaultFile" cached="true"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Comment" cached="false" storageId="Ugcdb" />
  <Item typeMapping="Rating" cached="false" storageId="Ugcdb" />
  <Item typeMapping="UGCUser" cached="false" storageId="Ugcdb" />
 <Item typeMapping="UGCItemStats" cached="false" storageId="Ugcdb" />
```

and if you want to save on physical path then also define the below tag value

```
<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultDataFile" defaultFilesystem="true" defaultStorage="true">
            <Root Path="c:\websites\Staging\data" />
        </Storage>
```

Let me know if it is not clear

Comment: Thanks Priyank. I have already set the root path for dynamic components in Deployer. But in that case all dynamic components are stored under a single folder irrespective of the folder structure available in CME. In my case i need to store the component in different folders(same like page content) based on the folder path in CME. Is there any way to achieve this without using any structure group concept.

Comment: You can only control the file system location of binaries and pages, not individual component presentations.

Comment: Thanks Nuno, is there any available deployer extension code to achieve this?